# How to Reference spaces and special characters in express-handlebars node js

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, special-characters, spaces

after hitting api i get this response which contains spaces and dot by which things are very confusing on how to render them in the handlebars

```
{
Meta Data: {
1. Information: "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
2. Symbol: "MSFT",
3. Last Refreshed: "2020-02-25 11:20:58",
4. Output Size: "Full size",
5. Time Zone: "US/Eastern"
},
Time Series (Daily): {
2020-02-25: {
1. open: "174.2000",
2. high: "174.8400",
3. low: "169.8800",
4. close: "170.4300",
5. adjusted close: "170.4300",
6. volume: "16881624",
7. dividend amount: "0.0000",
8. split coefficient: "1.0000"
},
2020-02-24: {
1. open: "167.7700",
2. high: "174.5500",
3. low: "163.2300",
4. close: "170.8900",
5. adjusted close: "170.8900",
6. volume: "67892482",
7. dividend amount: "0.0000",
8. split coefficient: "1.0000"
}
}
```

this is not working
i have tried many things the spaces and the dots are not allowing to render the code in the express handlebars.
please help

```
router.get('/stock/:name',(req,res)=>
{
    let name = req.params.name;
    console.log(name);
    axios.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${name}&apikey=apikey).then((result)=>
    {
        var newData1 = result.data;
        // console.log(newData1);
        res.render('home/stock',{newData1});
    })
})
```

how to render it in template
as spaces and dot are present in  the response

```
{{#each newData1}}


        {{#each 'Time Series (Daily)'}}
            <h5>{{this}}</h5>
        {{/each}}


{{/each}}
```

Comment: are you getting the "dots" when you call ```console.log(newData1);```?

Comment: maybe try ```res.render('home/stock',{newData1.json()});```

Comment: yes i am getting the dots while calling console.log(newData1);

Comment: maybe try res.render('home/stock',{newData1.json()}); not working  res.render('home/stock',{newData1.json()});
                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: what happens if you ```console.log(result);``` ?

Comment: after console.log(result); this is the result. <code>data: {
    'Meta Data': {
      '1. Information': 'Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events',
      '2. Symbol': 'INFY.NSE',
      '3. Last Refreshed': '2020-02-26',
      '4. Output Size': 'Compact',
      '5. Time Zone': 'US/Eastern'
    },
    'Time Series (Daily)': {
      '2020-02-26': [Object],
      '2020-02-24': [Object],
      '2020-02-20': [Object],
      '2020-02-19': [Object],
      '2020-02-18': [Object],
      '2020-02-17': [Object]}}</code>

Answer (score 0):

## The Problem

When you use the for-each in Handlebars you need to iterate through an array/list.
But your json (see below) does not contain any arrays/lists.

```
{
    "Meta Data":           {
                             "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
                             "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
                             "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-02-25 11:20:58",
                             "4. Output Size": "Full size",
                             "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
                           },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
                             "2020-02-25": {
                                             "1. open": "174.2000",
                                             "2. high": "174.8400",
                                             "3. low": "169.8800",
                                             "4. close": "170.4300",
                                             "5. adjusted close": "170.4300",
                                             "6. volume": "16881624",
                                             "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
                                             "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
                                           },
                             "2020-02-24": {
                                             "1. open": "167.7700",
                                             "2. high": "174.5500",
                                             "3. low": "163.2300",
                                             "4. close": "170.8900",
                                             "5. adjusted close": "170.8900",
                                             "6. volume": "67892482",
                                             "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
                                             "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
                                            }
}
```

## The solution

Below is a json that has arrays/lists.

```
[
    {"Meta Data":           [
                             {"1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events"},
                             {"2. Symbol": "MSFT"},
                             {"3. Last Refreshed": "2020-02-25 11:20:58"},
                             {"4. Output Size": "Full size"},
                             {"5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"}
                           ]},
    {"Time Series (Daily)": [
                            { "2020-02-25": [
                                             {"1. open": "174.2000"},
                                             {"2. high": "174.8400"},
                                             {"3. low": "169.8800"},
                                             {"4. close": "170.4300"},
                                             {"5. adjusted close": "170.4300"},
                                             {"6. volume": "16881624"},
                                             {"7. dividend amount": "0.0000"},
                                             {"8. split coefficient": "1.0000"}
                                           ]},
                             {"2020-02-24": [
                                             {"1. open": "167.7700"},
                                             {"2. high": "174.5500"},
                                             {"3. low": "163.2300"},
                                             {"4. close": "170.8900"},
                                             {"5. adjusted close": "170.8900"},
                                             {"6. volume": "67892482"},
                                             {"7. dividend amount": "0.0000"},
                                             {"8. split coefficient": "1.0000"}
                                            ]}
    ]}
]
```

So in order to create this new json, we are going to use `Node.js (JavaScript)` in the backend.

```
router.get('/stock/:name',(req,res)=>
{
    let name = req.params.name;
    console.log(name);
    axios.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${name}&apikey=apikey').then((result)=>
    {
        const newData1 = result.data;  // <-------- HERE, I will recommend 'const' instead of 'var' :)

        const timeSeriesDaily = newData1["Time Series (Daily)"];

        let timeSeriesDailyJSON = [] // <----- timeSeriesDailyJSON will be 'filled' in the for-loop below

        for (let dateIndex in timeSeriesDaily) {
            let array = timeSeriesDaily[dateIndex];
            let newArray = [];

            for(let index in array){
                newArray.push({
                                index: index,
                                value: array[index]
                             })
            }
            timeSeriesDailyJSON.push({
                                        date: dateIndex, 
                                        array: newArray
                                      });
       }

        res.render('home/stock', {timeSeriesDailyJSON});
    })
})
```

```
{{#each timeSeriesDailyJSON}}
    <h5>{{date}}</h5>
    {{#each array}}
        <h5>{{index}}</h5>
        <h5>{{value}}</h5>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Your solution Worked.. Thank You so much